# D3-delaunay does not return correct polygons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, leaflet, voronoi

I have got some points(DUMMY_POINTS) and i want to **divide my parent polygon**(polygonCoords) **into 3 small polygons** containing points that are the nearest to it. The problem is that the child polygons which i get as a result of Voronoi - are not correct.

**Point P should be in Polygon around "marker 2" instead of "marker 3"**

[Image showing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPd5t.jpg)

I think that the problem may be with voronoi bounds, because these two lines returns different results:

```
// const voronoi = Delaunay.from(points).voronoi();
const voronoi = Delaunay.from(points).voronoi(polygonBounds);
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { Polygon, Marker, useMap, useMapEvents } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

import styles from "./LaboratoryContainer.module.css";
import { isPointInPolygon } from "geolib";
import { Delaunay } from "d3-delaunay";

const fillBlueOptions = { fillColor: "blue" };
const fillRedOptions = { fillColor: "red", color: "red" };

const DUMMY_POINTS = [
    [49.87995048204671, 20.09553909301758],
    [49.883018280457776, 20.098800659179688],
    [49.88257583818168, 20.092234611511234],
];

const polygonCoords = [
    [
        { lat: 49.883488370933236, lng: 20.08762121200562 },
        { lat: 49.8774044934404, lng: 20.09470224380493 },
        { lat: 49.88055714384307, lng: 20.104873180389408 },
        { lat: 49.8856763053375, lng: 20.096912384033207 },
    ],
];

const polygonBounds = [49.8774044934404, 20.08762121200562, 49.8856763053375, 20.104873180389408];

const LaboratoryContainer = () => {
    const [pointToDelete, setPointToDelete] = useState([]);
    const [points, setPoints] = useState(DUMMY_POINTS);
    const [voronoiSections, setVoronoiSections] = useState([]);

    const map = useMap();

    const mapEvents = useMapEvents({
        click: (e) => {
            console.log(console.log(map.getSize()));
            if (isPointInPolygon(e.latlng, polygonCoords[0])) {
                setPoints((prevPoints) => {
                    return prevPoints.concat([[e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]]);
                });
                console.log([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]);
            }
        },
    });

    const eventHandlers = useMemo(
        () => ({
            dragstart(e) {
                setPointToDelete([e.target._latlng.lat, e.target._latlng.lng]);
            },
            dragend(e) {
                setPoints((prevPoints) => {
                    return prevPoints
                        .filter((point) => point[0] != pointToDelete[0] && point[1] != pointToDelete[1])
                        .concat([[e.target._latlng.lat, e.target._latlng.lng]]);
                });
            },
        }),
        []
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        // const voronoi = Delaunay.from(points).voronoi();
        const voronoi = Delaunay.from(points).voronoi(polygonBounds);

        const clipped = points.map((d, i) => voronoi.cellPolygon(i));

        const voronoiSectionsCoords = [];
        clipped.forEach((path) => {
            voronoiSectionsCoords.push(path);
        });
        setVoronoiSections(voronoiSectionsCoords);
    }, [points]);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Polygon pathOptions={fillRedOptions} positions={polygonCoords} />
            <div className={`leaflet-control ${styles["manager-container"]}`}></div>
            {points.map((point) => (
                <Marker eventHandlers={eventHandlers} draggable={true} position={point} />
            ))}
            {voronoiSections.map((coods) => (
                <Polygon pathOptions={fillBlueOptions} positions={coods} />
            ))}
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default LaboratoryContainer;
```

**==============EDIT================**

I have found out, that if i switch coordinates(lat <-> lng) then i get good results in the new area, however i dont know what to do with this hint.

[Good result but reversed coodinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8uA1.jpg)

```
const DUMMY_POINTS = [
    [20.09553909301758, 49.87995048204671],
    [20.098800659179688, 49.883018280457776],
    [20.092234611511234, 49.88257583818168],
];

const polygonCoords = [
    [
        { lng: 49.883488370933236, lat: 20.08762121200562 },
        { lng: 49.8774044934404, lat: 20.09470224380493 },
        { lng: 49.88055714384307, lat: 20.104873180389408 },
        { lng: 49.8856763053375, lat: 20.096912384033207 },
    ],
];

const polygonBounds = [20.08762121200562, 49.8774044934404, 20.104873180389408, 49.8856763053375];
```